# meaning of $(this) at the jQuery top level

Tags: jquery, html, dom, this, element

I understand the meaning of `$(this)` inside an event handler.

```
$("div#d1").on("mouseover", function() {
  $(this).attr("id", "d2");
  alert("id: " + $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

but However, when it used at the top level of jQuery code, what does that mean?

```
var tgt = $("h2#slider");
tgt.hide();
tgt.slideDown(2000);
$(this).on("click", function() {
  tgt.slideUp(); 
});
```

Comment: `this` at the root level will refer to the [`window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window). Wrapping it in [`$(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) returns it as a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery). Related documentations linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` at the root level refers to the window object.
https://jsfiddle.net/z20x9owq/

Answer (score 0):

When Used inside a callback `Jquery "$(this)"` refers to the current DOM element
but when used outside a callback, `$(this)` is an array which has the Window object on the 0th index, same as the `Javascript` "this" keyword which is also Window object when used outside a function.
A good example is:

```
console.log($(this)===this); //return false
console.log($(this)[0]===this); //return true
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

"this" is a html element and hasn't "on" method or any jQuery method. You have to convert it to jquery element with $(this) for using the "on" method